# Why the code is stopping after first f-string?

Tags: python, f-string

I'm trying to print out two statements on the basis of provided dictionary, but something goes wrong and the code is stopping after the first f-string (the second isn't displayed). I suppose that it might be something similar, but can't figure out the mistake:

```
data = [
{
    'name': 'Instagram',
    'follower_count': 346,
    'description': 'Social media platform',
    'country': 'United States'
},
{
    'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
    'follower_count': 215,
    'description': 'Footballer',
    'country': 'Portugal'
}]

a = input(f"Compare A: {data[1]['name']}, {data[1]['description']}, from {data[1]['country']}")
b = input(f"Compare B: {data[0]['name']}, {data[0]['description']}, from {data[0]['country']}")
```

Comment: input `input` stops and asks the user to enter something.

try print instead

Comment: You're calling `input()`, which pauses the program until the user types something and presses Enter.  If you just want to display the strings, use `print()`.

Comment: Thank you! Now all is clear)

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
data = [
{
    'name': 'Instagram',
    'follower_count': 346,
    'description': 'Social media platform',
    'country': 'United States'
},
{
    'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
    'follower_count': 215,
    'description': 'Footballer',
    'country': 'Portugal'
}]

a = print(f"Compare A: {data[1]['name']}, {data[1]['description']}, from {data[1]['country']}")
b = print(f"Compare B: {data[0]['name']}, {data[0]['description']}, from {data[0]['country']}")
```

Here is the result:

```
Compare A: Cristiano Ronaldo, Footballer, from Portugal
Compare B: Instagram, Social media platform, from United States
```

Comment: What is the point of assigning a and b to the result of print, which does not return anything?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how to print a and b:

```
data = [
{
    'name': 'Instagram',
    'follower_count': 346,
    'description': 'Social media platform',
    'country': 'United States'
},
{
    'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
    'follower_count': 215,
    'description': 'Footballer',
    'country': 'Portugal'
}]
```

print("Compare A: {" + data[1]['name'] + "}, {" + data[1]['description'] + "}, " + "from {" + data[1]['country']"}")
print("Compare B: {" + data[0]['name']+ "}, {" + data[0]['description'] + "}," + "from {" + data[0]['country'] + "}")

Comment: What is the point of assigning a and b to the result of print, which does not return anything?

Comment: lol you are right. I was just trying to type the answer as fast as possible. Missed that spot! thx